# Dynamic form in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, django-forms

I am trying to make a dynamic form in Django that asks according to the user's answers. For example, in this google form when you select option 1, it sends you to the section of option 1 with their respective questions.

[Google Form Example](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScxrtB-uWuPrRrrZMcQTJQC-Eb1uF0S1ElPE9p0BcUwzcGU0Q/viewform?usp=sf_link)

Comment: That is not a dymamic form: it simply submits that form and based on the value selected, it renders a new page, optionally with a new form...

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you. What would be the best option if I don't want another page to be rendered.